# How to Require SSL on a specific Page Type but not on the parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https, kentico

I'd like to know if Kentico has a "best practice" way to ensure the *Requires SSL* property is set as *Yes* on a specific Page Type, without inheriting the property from the Parent page.

I have researched this and have implemented a working solution (below) but am interested to know if there is a better "out of the box" solution that I may have overlooked.

We are using Kentico v8.2 with ASPX + Portal Page Types.

**Our technical requirements**

1. Serve the parent listing page over HTTP or HTTPS
2. Serve the child pages over HTTPS only

**Our use case scenario**

The user browses a page listing Job Vacancies. The user opens a specific Job Vacancy page which contains an Application Form. The user is confident entering personal details into the Application Form as the page is served over a secure connection.

**Considered solutions**

The closest "out of the box" solution I could find was to set the parent listing page to *Require SSL = Yes* and then inherit this on the child pages, however this doesn't meet our technical requirement to allow the listing page to be served over HTTP.

I also decided against manually setting *Requires SSL = Yes* on each child page as I didn't want to place this burden on the CMS Editors, give them more permissions than necessary and open it up to human error.

**Current solution**

So I ended up writing a Custom Event handler to set the Requires SSL property on *Document Insert* or *Document Update* events.

Initially I was doing this based on Page Type (Node.ClassName) but changed it to be based on a Field value so that I could more easily apply this to other Page Types by simply adding a field without refactoring my code and deploying a DLL.

```
[CustomEvents]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    private class CustomEvents : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        public override void Init() { 
            DocumentEvents.Insert.Before += Document_Insert_Before;
            DocumentEvents.Update.Before += Document_Update_Before;
        }

        void Document_Insert_Before(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            SetRequiresSSL(e.Node);
        }

        void Document_Update_Before(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
        {
            SetRequiresSSL(e.Node);
        }

        private void SetRequiresSSL(TreeNode node)
        {
            //if RequiresSecureConnection field is equal to true
            if (node.GetBooleanValue("RequiresSecureConnection", false))
            {
                //if Requires SSL is not Yes
                if (node.RequiresSSL != 1)
                {
                    //set Requires SSL
                    node.RequiresSSL = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Related urls**

- https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Configuring+SSL
- https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Reference+-+Global+system+events
- https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Handling+global+events

Comment: So, you don't have to answer, but I'm very curious.  Why aren't you just encrypting traffic in the first place?

Comment: @Jerreck Do you mean why don't we just serve the entire website over HTTPS? It would solve the problem but I understand there are some valid reasons not to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746047/why-not-use-https-for-everything

Comment: @DarrenS The 3 reason of the accepted answer are not valid any more, and the *only* protection against MITM it to use https for the full website and use HSTS (preloaded if possible)

Comment: @Tom I agree that the answer I referenced is old. You raise valid points and I accept there are some good reasons to move to full HTTPS not least of which is the push from Google https://moz.com/blog/seo-tips-https-ssl, I'm sure you can appreciate that before we move to full HTTPS we'd have technical and SEO implications to consider which aren't in scope at this stage. While the question I asked was about leveraging a specific feature in Kentico CMS, I do appreciate the comment, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve out of the box without any customisation and still make it editable if you use the system attribute on the page type:

- Open you page type
- add a new field
- select Field type : Page field
- select Group : Node fields
- select field name : RequiresSSL
- enter a default value : 1 (which is YES for this type)
- **Deselect** the Display field in editing form so the editor wont see it.

[image: requiresSSL]

This way all pages created based on this page type will have the RequiresSSL preselected. And it's still adjustable.

David

Comment: Is there a way to force it to always be Yes? By using a default field = 1 it will set it to Yes on insert but if someone (with permission) changed the RequireSSL value in Pages > Properties > Security > RequireSSL to No it would no longer be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Well you have the "Validation" but this is only available if you display the field in the editing form. You could make the editing control a label (so it's not adjustable). Otherwise your document event in code is a good alternative.